# I get "unintentionally" mqtt topics with old values. how can I delete topics

Tags: mqtt, reset, broker

My mqtt broker runs very well and reliably on a Raspberry 3B;

However, I get "unintentionally"  mqtt topics with old values. (probably connecting corpses)
1: How can I reset the broker or delete (not unscribe) individual topics
2: How can I determine the client where or why the values come from?

I'm using python 3.7, it would be great to get a hint for python,

I've already tried this without success:
First we have to stop the mosquitto broker.

sudo systemctl stop mosquitto.service
or
sudo service mosquitto stop

Delete the mosquitto.db containing all the stored message data in the persistence. By default, located in /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db

sudo rm /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db

Restart the mosquitto service

sudo systemctl start mosquitto.service
or
sudo service mosquitto start

Comment: Just unsuscribe the topic on client side and also make the retain flag as False if you dont need the old values.

Comment: Hi Hsn Thank you for very quick answer; but sorry for asking : how can I set retain flag. My client is a ESP8266. I tried to unsubscribe but no mo success.

Comment: From where are these values coming? you need to disable it from the publisher side..